# find efficient way to calculate 1NN

Tags: python, machine-learning, computer-science, metrics, knn

trying to find the smallest dinstance between one vector of test set to the whole train set , I have a really intuitive function
that computing it , but when I want to compute it to the whole test set , its taking me whole lots of time , do you have some idea of implementing it ( maybe with CUDA, is it could help with GPU power) ?

```
#testX - test set - numpy.ndarray(flatten img's)
#trainX - train set -numpy.ndarray(flatten img's)

ans = []

def metric(test, train):
    return np.linalg.norm(test-train,np.inf) 

def serch_min_dist(test):
    return  min((metric(test, train), i) for i, train in enumerate(trainX))

for i in range(len(testX)) : # for each test instance
    minimum_d = serch_min_dist(testX[i], label)[0]
    ans.append(minimum_d)
```

Comment: I'm not sure but maybe you can use tensorflow: `tf.convert_to_tensor` and then `vector.device` to send tensor to a GPU, then do the computation. Maybe this could help.

Comment: What is in a train and test variables? (`pandas.DataFrame`, `tf.Tensor`, `numpy.ndarray`) Could you provide and example of rows from each set?

Comment: numpy.ndarray , its flatten images